# How to remap the key combination to change to the next tab in my browser (Ubuntu 21.10)?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, remapping

I’m using Ubuntu 21.10

I want to change the key command used to switch browser tabs to mimic what I do on Mac (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⇠</kbd> / <kbd>⇢</kbd>), instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[The documentation suggests](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) this can be done by going to Settings->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts and searching...but I can't find anything that looks relevant.

I'm using the Brave and Chromium browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Forget what the documentation suggests: that is only for system wide shortcuts. Here, you will need to change a way for the shortcuts in your specific browser (whichever that is). Because the solution will depend on the browser, better specify it in your question.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, I added info on the browsers.  I'll also take a look at the docs for those and see if I can discover where/how to override.

Answer (score 0):

This apparently isn't possible in Brave currently, there's a long running issue tracking it: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/354

For Chromium docs suggest: https://www.alphr.com/customize-chrome-hotkeys/